# How to remove reference to removed DC from the network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I recently demoted a win2kr2 DC from my network, unfortunate for me I remove the entire Server from the Network physically as well.  Now I am facing with numerous ADDS Repl. Errors (Obviously)  How do I remove the record of my removed DC from my network for GOOD?

Comment: How did you demote the DC because depending on the steps you took there could be dozens of references to that old Dc still remaining...

Comment: I used dcpromo /force command

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up the forest metadata.  [Here's a TechNet article on how to do it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907%28WS.10%29.aspx).

The problem is that you used dcpromp /forceremoval to demote the DC.  That switch should only ever be used as a last resort to get a botched domain controller off the network and it won't demote gracefully.

If that DC had any FSMO roles on it you will likely have to seize them.

Comment: I already have seized the FSMO roles to another dc and that is working fine.  Its just I am seeing replication errors pointing to the removed DC in my Event Viewer.... Thank you for the article.  I will go through this and let you know what happened.....cheers